# Adding "fixed" key to referenced attribute not working

Tags: xml, xsd

1.xsd file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<xs:attribute name="debuggable" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:schema>
```

2.xsd file:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:import xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" namespace="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" schemaLocation="1.xsd" />
...
            <xs:attribute ref="android:debuggable" use="optional" fixed="false" />
...
```

When I tried to call `assertValid` using file 2.xsd, it would fail to detect `debuggable` set to `true`. However, when I move `fixed="false"` to 1.xsd (still load file 2 as schema), it would work. Is it because the key in file 2 is referencing attribute in file 1 and cannot add more properties to it? Anyway to go around it without modifying file 1?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out there is something whacked with `lxml`... and I'll try to figure out in a later time. I replaced `lxml` library with `xmlschema` without changing anything and everything works like a charm.

`assertValid` in `lxml` returned true when `is_valid` in `xmlschema` returned false, quite a strange case.

Hopefully this would help someone save a bit of time if you ever encounter it.